# DOMDocument and dom module in PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am developing an application with php where I need to use XML files and transform them by using a XSL style sheet. To load the XML and XSL files I use the following:

```
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load("myxslfile.xsl");  // load XSL
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load("myxmlfile.xml");  // load XML
```

the problem is when running the code the next error appears:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyDirectory\DOMDocument' not found in 'mydirectory'
```

Running `phpinfo()` I can see dom is intalled and enabled. I don't know why I can't run `DOMDocument()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are apparently using the [namespace](http://php.net/namespaces) `MyDirectory`. But `DOMDocument` is a class in the global namespace. To reference a class from the global namespace in a local namespace you have to use the Fully Qualified Name or import it into the local namespace:

#### Fully Qualified Namespace:

```
$xsl = new \DOMDocument();
$xsl->load("myxslfile.xsl");  // load XSL
$xml = new \DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load("myxmlfile.xml");  // load XML
```

#### Importing with `use`

```
namespace MyDirectory;
use \DOMDocument;

$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load("myxslfile.xsl");  // load XSL
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load("myxmlfile.xml");  // load XML
```